# Spinnaker on AWS: Create application hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm having trouble creating a new application on Spinnaker after following the [quickstart guide for AWS](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/). The server runs fine on Port 9000 and I've enabled Port 8084 (via AWS Security Group) for Deck/Gate to run.

However, when I try to create a new project on the UI, the menu hangs [like shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf8sb.png).

I've tried configuring and running this setup several times now, however I cannot get past this part. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked on things some more and was able to fix my problem. I realized that Spinnaker needs Authentication set up as mentioned in this [FAQ](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/faq/).

I opted to [expose my Spinnaker to end users](https://blog.spinnaker.io/exposing-spinnaker-to-end-users-4808bc936698) (likely to change in the near future). While I enabled Gate and Deck to listen on 0.0.0.0, I did *not* associate a domain name with them which caused things not to work. After associating them with a domain name, I was able to make a new application.